# Jmeter - Error when using variable to hold CSV variable names

Tags: csv, variables, jmeter, configuration-files

Running some tests successfully in jmeter and am now parameterising them and have come across the following problem.

I am using a csv file which contains a number of variables I am using in the tests.
Within my test I have defined the CSV variables in the following format:

```
Title,ResponseCode,CheckForTest,ExpectedData
```

This works fine when that is defined in the CSV config processor.

However, when I try to put that into a properties file in the form:

```
TESTVARS=Title,ResponseCode,CheckForTest,ExpectedData
```

I get this error:

```
Could not split CSV header line jav.io.IOException: Missing trailing quote-char in quoted field:["]
```

Any idea what this means, and how I fix it?

Not that I am using v2.13 of jmeter and cannot use an upgraded version at the moment so I need a solution for v2.13

Many thanks

Comment: If you are defining properties (`jmeter.properties` or `user.properties`), you must use `key=value`. which one did you update? Please share the screenshot of the properties file highlighting the entries. Note: You MUST restart JMeter if you update the properties.

Comment: I'm amending a local properties file. Can't provide a screenshot as it is on a separate system. I am getting similarly bad behaviour when I try and change Port Number and Path with my http request.

Comment: Is there a limit on the field length for any of the parameters? My list of csv variables is quite long.

Comment: I'm not aware of any limitations on field length. May I know properties file name? As I said, you must define properties using 'key=value' syntax.

Comment: Properties file is called 'Address_jmeter.properties' and is in the same directory as my jmx file. I've been trying to get the Port number into a http request from it, using variable PORTNUM=12345 and this is erroring. I'm using ${PORTNUM} within the http request. As far as I understand it, that is the correct format.

Comment: I'm not sure whether you can define a custom properties file. please define it in `user.properties` file which is in same directory with `PORTNUM=12345` and restart JMeter. Yes, accessing is correct, `${PORTNUM}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When looking at JMeter source code:

```
    String i$ = server.reserveFile(threadVars, this.getFileEncoding(), this.alias, true);
    try {
      this.vars = CSVSaveService.csvSplitString(i$, delim.charAt(0));
      this.firstLineIsNames = true;
    } catch (IOException var11) {
      throw new IllegalArgumentException("Could not split CSV header line from file:" + threadVars, var11);
    }
```

Apparently, it cannot read the header of your CSV file, and split it to variable names.

Comment: That's what I thought too. The problem I had was that when I added a header line the tests failed badly, but this seems to have resolved itself now and the header is working fine. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Be kind to mark the answer as correct if it solved your issue. :)

Answer (score 1):

Properties are different beasts, you need to remember few things:

1. JMeter needs to be restarted to pick the properties up
2. You need to use [__P()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__P) or [__property()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__property) function in order to access property values so if you used `${TESTVARS}` somewhere in your script you need to convert it to `${__property(TESTVARS)}`
3. Always look into *jmeter.log* file - it's the primary source of the troubleshooting information

If above hints don't help - kindly update your question with your properties file (first few lines), the command line, you're using to run JMeter and how you are trying to access the property value.

References:

- [Configuring JMeter](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#configuring_jmeter)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)
- [Full list of JMeter command-line options](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options)